# IOS App Delegate

Tags: ios, appdelegate

I would appreciate your opinion about the usage, nowadays, of the following code for accessing global variables, for creating an app in IOS 5 and above

```
ProjectAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ProjectAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Is the above considered as Object Oriented Programming ?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't ask if it is considered Object-oriented programming. Object-oriented programming is a separate topic regarding the use of interacting objects with both attributes and methods. This isn't relevant to your question -- which is the use of accessing global variables in the AppDelegate.

I think what you're really asking is if it's good programming style to place global variables in the AppDelegate and then access the variables anywhere in the program (such as different view controllers) using the line of code

```
ProjectAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ProjectAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

The AppDelegate is really just a class that is a "listener". The class has delegate methods that are called when the app changes state, such as during launching, entering background, terminating, etc. It's a chance for your application to respond to these changes of application state, and it should be used that way.

The reason putting global variables in the AppDelegate may seem useful is because the AppDelegate is really a shared class (singleton) that can be accessed anywhere in your application. However, that still doesn't make it intended to hold global variables.

It really just depends on your app's architecture and how you follow the model-view-controller paradigm. Here's an example: If you were to implement CoreLocation in the AppDelegate to get the user's location, then you could access the user location data from any other class in the project. However, you could just as easily have a separate location manager class and then use NSNotification to notify other classes that a new location has been found. A third possibility is to make the Location manager class a shared singleton and then access the global data. In the end, all three work, and it just depends how you architect your application.

However, I would do my best to keep the AppDelegate specific to responding to changes of the application state. I would avoid putting too many global variables in the AppDelegate because it's not what the AppDelegate is intended for.

Comment: Thank you for your time and by the the way I mentioned OOP considering the ownership of the data which probably is irrelevant;

Comment: no problem, please accept the answer if there's nothing else you're looking for

Comment: Many programmers try and decouple their architecture by creating components that communicate with each other through some kind of messaging system. It is important to understand that all such systems ultimately rely to some kind of central node which handles the passing of data from one component to the other. PureMVC for example has the concept of the Facade. I often use the AppDelegate for a similar role.